# discordpy how can i display the shard id in my stats command?

Tags: discord.py

### does anyone know how i can display the shard id the ping and servers of that shard id in my stats command!

I have some variables for shardID/shardPING/shardSERVERS

Thats my stats command:

```py
@commands.command(aliases=["botstats"])
    async def stats(self, ctx):

        dpyVersion = discord.__version__
        serverCount = len(self.bot.guilds)
        memberCount = len(set(self.bot.get_all_members()))

        shardID = "ID"
        shardPING = "PING"
        shardSERVERS = "SERVERS"

        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{self.bot.user.name} - Stats')

        embed.add_field(name='Bot Version:', value=self.bot.version)
        embed.add_field(name='Discord.Py Version:', value=dpyVersion)
        embed.add_field(name='Total Guilds:', value=serverCount)
        embed.add_field(name='Total Users:', value=memberCount)
        embed.add_field(name='Shard ID:', value=shardID)
        embed.add_field(name='Shard Ping:', value=shardPING)
        embed.add_field(name='Shard Servers:', value=shardSERVERS)

        embed.set_thumbnail(url=thumbnail)
        embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `shard_id` you can get it really easily, just `ctx.guild.shard_id`, to get all the other variables you first need a `ShardInfo` instance:

```py
shard_id = ctx.guild.shard_id
shard = self.bot.get_shard(shard_id)
shard_ping = shard.latency
shard_servers = len([guild for guild in self.bot.guilds if guild.shard_id == shard_id])
```

The `shard_servers` variable is a simple list-comprehension that checks for the guild's shard ID